# AWS EB Route Problem When Passing Encoded Param

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a route that passes a value through req.params `app.get('/someroute/:val' => res.send(req.params.val))`. This value is actually a URL that's been encoded.

I have no problem hitting this route through localhost. However, when I deploy this to Elastic-Beanstalk and I try out the route, I get a 404 Error, stating that this route can't be found.

Is there some configuration I'm missing?

```
app.get('/someroute/:url', (req, res) => {
  let uri = decodeURI(req.params.url);
  Promise.all([reqFileOne.getRequest(), reqFileTwo.getRequest(uri)])
    .then(d => res.json(d));
});
```

I'd like to be able to hit the route, and get the send the json response as it does on my local machine.

On AWS Elastic-Beanstalk, I unfortunately get a 404.

Comment: So I decided to instead pass on a query string and the route does get hit. I added back the Promise array and it's functioning like it should. Unfortunately, now I'm getting a 504. Besides the new development, I'm still curious why the req.params isn't working working?

Answer (score 0):

Add some debugging to output the value of `uri` before the promise to check it’s what you expect.

Suggest you use decodeURIComponent instead of decodeURI as it’s considered more reliable. It’s possible in Elastic Beanstalk the URI decode ends up with unescaped characters giving a malformed URI resulting in a 404.

```
app.get('/someroute/:url', (req, res) => {
  let uri = decodeURIComponent(req.params.url);
  Promise.all([reqFileOne.getRequest(), reqFileTwo.getRequest(uri)])
.then(d => res.json(d));
});
```

If you are doing the encode you should use encodeURIComponent instead of encodeURI as well.

Comment: Still stumped, I got rid of the promise, and decided to just put a `res.send('test')` and I'm still getting a 404. I switched decodeURI to decodeURIComponent now.

Comment: Actually I emptied out the entire arrow function, and just added a `res.send('test')` and I still get the 404. Does AWS not like req.params or something?

Comment: @Edrich at the risk of stating the obvious, you're troubleshooting the wrong problem.  If emptying the function still gives you a 404, then the route `'/someroute/:url'` *is not matching the incoming request at all.*  You need to troubleshoot *that*.  Make a test request for something simpler, like `/someroute/foo`. Does that execute the function and set `url` to "foo"?  If not, why not?  The problem is not the decode -- your code is never getting to that point.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - sqlbot I understand, but I do have other routes that do get hit. Just to make sure, I rewrote the route from `'/someroute/:url'` to `'/someroute/foo'` and this worked. Since this is getting hit, can we assume that something's wrong with passing params from the route?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting redefining the route... I was suggesting testing the existing route with a simpler parameter value -- no url escaped characters, no special/potentially problematic characters.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I did as you: A simple "/someroute/test" still gave a 404. I understand that this doesn't get hit when deployed in AWS, but this does get hit on localhost.